# The health, safety and well-being of our employees "is"/"are"

Tags: grammar

What is more correct?

a) The health, safety and well-being of our employees is mission priority #1.

b) The health, safety and well-being of our employees are mission priority #1.

Comment: This has been done here before. If "health, safety and well-being" is a noun phrase indicating closely related items, then it takes singular verb. If they are unrelated, it takes a plural verb. For me, this seems like singular.

Comment: If you *did* have plural three things, they can't all be priority #1.

Comment: Think of it this way: " Our number one priority is _the health, safety, and well-being of our employees_".